# Wildcard searching including a wildcard that indicates any word in the word list

Tags: search, text, structure, wildcard

I have a word list of around 250,000 English words or short phrases. I'm trying to write some code that will allow wildcard searching of them. Specifically, three wildcards should be permitted:

"." represents a single character
"*" represents any zero or more characters
">" represents a word present in the word list, each of length at least two.

For instance, "a.>k" would return words including antitank (here > matches "titan"), and "ca.>>" would return words including "calendaring" (cal EN DARING). One more example, since those didn't include "*": "kh>*a>" should return words including "khmermountains" (kh ME ermount a INS)

Obviously dealing with "." and "*" is trivial through regular expressions or whatever. I'm finding how to think about implementing ">" efficiently more difficult. So my question is: what general approach would people try here? Is there a particular data structure I should learn about that is suited to such problems? Or am I just missing some obvious trick?

Obviously one horribly inefficient way would be to try to substitute each ">" in the query with each word in the list in turn and run a wildcard search for each. There must be a far better way; one thing that convinces me that there is is [this website primarily for crossword-solving that does similar things](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=a%3E%3E%3Eb%3E%3E%3E&ent=Search&dict=0) which can run such a search very rapidly indeed.